# How can we prove $\int_a^bf\:{\rm d}g=\int_a^bf(s)g'(s)\:{\rm d}s$ if $g'$ is not continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, riemann-integration, stieltjes-integral

Let $a,b\in\mathbb R$ with $a<b$, $$\mathcal D_{[a,\:b]}:=\{(t_0,\ldots,t_k):k\in\mathbb N\text{ and }a=t_0<\cdots<t_k\}$$ and $$\mathcal T_\varsigma:=\{(\tau_1,\ldots,\tau_k):\tau_i\in[t_{i-1},t_i]\text{ for all }i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}\}\;\;\;\text{for }\varsigma=(t_0,\ldots,t_k)\in\mathcal D_{[a,\:b]}.$$ Moreover, let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be continuous and $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be of bounded variation. We can show that $$\int_a^bf\:{\rm d}g:=\lim_{\substack{|\varsigma|\to0+\\\varsigma\in\mathcal D_{[a,\:b]}\\\tau\in\mathcal T_\varsigma}}S_{\varsigma,\:\tau}(f,g)$$ is well-defined, where $$|\varsigma|:=\max_{1\le i\le k}(t_i-t_{i-1})\;\;\;\text{for }\varsigma=(t_0,\ldots,t_k)\in\mathcal D_{[a,\:b]}$$ and $$S_{\varsigma,\:\tau}(f,g):=\sum_{i=1}^kf(\tau_i)(g(t_i)-g(t_{i-1}))\;\;\;\text{for }\varsigma=(t_0,\ldots,t_k)\in\mathcal D_{[a,\:b]}\text{ and }\tau\in\mathcal T_\varsigma.$$

> Assuming that $g$ is differentiable (not necessarily *continuously* differentiable), are we able to show that $$\int_a^bf\:{\rm d}g=\int_a^bf(s)g'(s)\:{\rm d}s\tag1?$$

Let $\varsigma=(t_0,\ldots,t_k)\in\mathcal D_{[a,\:b]}$. By the mean value theorem, there is a $\tau\in\mathcal T_\varsigma$ with $$S_{\varsigma,\:\tau}(f,g)=\sum_{i=1}^kf(\tau_i)g'(\tau_i)(t_i-t_{i-1})=S_{\varsigma,\:\tau}(fg',\operatorname{id}_{[a,\:b]})\tag2,$$ but does the right-hand side tend to the right-hand side of $(1)$ as $|\varsigma|\to0+$? This is clearly the case when $g'$ is continuous though ...

Comment: A sufficient condition is that $g$ is almost everywhere differentiable (which is the case when $g$ has bounded variation) and $g'$ is Lebesgue integrable so that $g(x)-g(a) = \int_a^x g'(t) \, dt$.

Comment: @RRL Thank you for your comment. Please take note of my comment below [the answer below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4468334/47771). Do you know whether the result is applicable in the scenario from the other question?

Comment: @RRL Is that a sufficient condition? Let $g$ be the [Cantor fucntion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), then $g$ is almost everywhere differentiable with $g'=0$ a.e., so $g'$ is Lebesgue integrable, but we have $g(1)-g(0)\neq 0=\int_0^1 g'(t)\,dt$.  What's more, if $g$ is of bounded variation, then $g$ is differentiable a.e. and $g'\in L^1$, so your early comment implies that the fundamental theorem of caclulus holds for functions having bounded variation, which is not the case. Am I right?

Comment: I remember that if $g$ is everywhere differnetiable (not 'almost everywhere', but 'everywhere') with $g'$ Lebesgue integrable, then the fundamental theorem holds for $g$.

Comment: @Feng: I am not implying that at all. I am saying that integrability of f’ is one of the sufficient conditions.

Comment: @RRL I was saying that if $g$ has bounded variation, then both conditions you mentioned are satisfied, but we don't necessarily have $g(x)-g(a)=\int_a^x g'(t)\,dt$.....Wait, I think you maybe mean that the equality $g(x)-g(a)=\int_a^x g'(t)\,dt$ is one of the sufficient conditions??? If so, then no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following claims hold:

> **Theorem 1.** Let $g$ be absolutely continuous on $[a, b]$, and let $f$ be continuous on $[a, b]$. Then $fg'$ is Lebesgue integrable and
> $$ \int_{a}^{b} f(t) \, \mathrm{d}g(t) = \int_{a}^{b} f(t)g'(t) \, \mathrm{d}t. $$

The proof is quite simple. Starting from the fact that $\int_{c}^{d} g'(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = g(d) - g(c)$ for any interval $[c, d] \subseteq [a, b]$ (where we utilized the [absolute continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) of $g$), the statement holds when $f$ is a step function. Then the desired claim follows by choosing a sequence of step functions that converges uniformly to $f$. This reasoning in fact shows that the statement remains true if $f$ is a uniform limit of step functions, i.e., [regulated functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulated_function).

Also, if the left-hand side is understood as the [Lebesgue–Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration) sense, then the equality holds for any $f$ that is integrable with respect to the measure $|g'(t)| \, \mathrm{d}t$. This is because the above statement reduces to an instance of the [Radon–Nikodym theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem). This opens up possibilities of further generalizing the above claim.

We also have:

> **Theorem 2.** Let $g$ be differentiable everywhere on $[a, b]$, and let $f$ be both Riemann–Stieltjes integrable with respect to $g$ and Lebesgue integrable on $[a, b]$. Then $fg'$ is Henstock–Kurzweil integrable and
> $$ \int_{a}^{b} f(t) \, \mathrm{d}g(t) = \int_{a}^{b} f(t)g'(t) \, \mathrm{d}t, $$
> where the right-hand side is in [Henstock–Kurzweil integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock%E2%80%93Kurzweil_integral) sense.

The Henstock–Kurzweil integral can be thought as a non-absolutely convergent version of the Lebesgue integral, in the sense that a function $f$ is Lebesgue integrable if and only if both $f$ and $|f|$ is Henstock–Kurzweil integrable.

The proof is also straightforward, assuming basic theory of all the types of integral mentioned above. Indeed, for each $\varepsilon > 0$, we do the following:

- Let $\varepsilon' = \frac{\varepsilon}{\int_{a}^{b} |f|+2}$. Since $f$ is Lebesgue integrable, this is still a positive number.
- Choose a number $\delta_1 > 0$ such that $\left| S(f, g, \dot{\mathcal{P}}) - \int_{a}^{b} f \, \mathrm{d}g \right| < \varepsilon'$ for any [tagged partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_an_interval) $\dot{\mathcal{P}}$ with mesh size $ < \delta_1$. This is possible since $f$ is Riemann–Stieltjes integrable with respect to $g$.
- Choose a gauge $\delta_2$ satisfying the straddle lemma for $g$ and $\varepsilon'$: For any $t \in [a, b]$ and $u, v \in [a, b]$ satisfying $t - \delta_2(t) < u < t < v < t + \delta_2(t)$,
  $$ |g(v) - g(u) - g'(t)(v - u)| \leq \varepsilon' (v - u). $$
- Choose a gauge $\delta_3$ such that $\left| S(|f|, \dot{\mathcal{P}}) - \int_{a}^{b} |f| \right| < 1$ for any $\delta_3$-fine tagged partition $\dot{\mathcal{P}}$. This is possible because $|f|$ is Lebesgue integrable and hence Henstock–Kurzweil integrable.

Now let $\delta(t) = \min\{\delta_1, \delta_2(t), \delta_3(t)\} $. Then $\delta_3$ is also a gauge, and for any $\delta$-fine tagged partition $\dot{\mathcal{P}}$ of $[a, b]$,

\begin{align*}
\left| \int_{a}^{b} f \, \mathrm{d}g - S(fg', \dot{\mathcal{P}}) \right|
&\leq \left| \int_{a}^{b} f \, \mathrm{d}g - S(f, g, \dot{\mathcal{P}}) \right|
+ \left| S(f, g, \dot{\mathcal{P}}) - S(fg', \dot{\mathcal{P}}) \right| \\
&< \varepsilon' + \sum_{i} |f(\tau_i)| \cdot |g(t_i) - g(t_{i-1}) - g'(\tau_i)(t_i - t_{i-1})| \\
&\leq \varepsilon' + \varepsilon' \sum_{i} |f(\tau_i)| (t_i - t_{i-1}) \\
&\leq \varepsilon' + \varepsilon' \left( 1 + \int_{a}^{b} |f| \right) \\
&= \varepsilon.
\end{align*}

Therefore the desired claim follows.

Comment: Actually, I don't this formula to hold, but I need what the derivative of the left-hand side with respect to the upper bound would be if it holds. Could you please take a look at [the question I've asked for that](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4481540/47771)?

Comment: Do you have any precise book reference of the statement of Theorem 1 above @SangchulLee? I have tried to search this result on classical analysis books but failed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)  dg= \int f(x)\frac{dg}{dx} dx =\int_{a}^t f(x) g'(x) dx+\int_{t}^{b} f(x) g'(x) dx,$

where $g'(x)$ has a finite jump discontinuity at $x=t$.

**Edit:**

For example let $f(x)=x, g(x)=|x|$, then g'(x)= \text{sgn}(x) is discontinuous at $x=0$, so we have

$I=\int_{-1}^2 x d|x|= \int_{-1}^{2} x \frac{d|x|}{dx} dx=\int_{-1}^{2} x ~\text{sgn}(x)~ dx= \int_{-1}^{0} x (-1) dx+ \int_{0}^{2} x.1 dx=\frac{1}{2}+2=\frac{5}{2}.$

Comment: So, it is enough to assume that $g'$ is regular (i.e. $g'(t\pm):=\lim_{s\to t\pm}g'(s)$ exists for all $t\in[a,b]$), right? I guess this is related to the formula $$h_1(t)h_2(t)=h_1(0)h_2(0)+\int_{(0,\:t]}h_1(s-)\:{\rm d}h_2(s)+\int_{(0,\:t]}h_2(s-)\:{\rm d}h_1(s)+\sum_{s\in(0,\:t]}\Delta h_1(s)\Delta h_2(s)$$ for all right-continuous $f,g:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ with locally finite variation, where $\Delta f(s):=f(s)-f(s-)$ for $s\ge0$.

Comment: Yes, I am sure about it.

Comment: Also, you may see my Edit above.