# If $g$ is bounded, nondecreasing and right-continuous, how do we show $\int f(t)\:{\rm d}g(t)=\int f(t)g'(t)\:{\rm d}t$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, stieltjes-integral

Let $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be bounded, nondecreasing and right-continuous and $\mu_g$ denote the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure on $\mathcal B([0,\infty))$ associated with $g$.

Moreover, let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. [We know](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4477179/47771) that $g$ is differentiable $\lambda$-almost everywhere.

However, are we able to show that $$\int f\:\mu_g=\int fg'\:{\rm d}\lambda\tag1$$ for all $f\in\mathcal L^1(\mu_g)$? If not, what do we need to assume to make this claim true?

I know that the claim is true if $g$ is **continuously** differentiable (everywhere), but does it hold in general?

**EDIT**: It is known that if $h:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is locally Lebesgue integrable, then $$r(t):=\int_{-\infty}^th(s)\:{\rm d}s\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ is differentiable Lebesgue almost everywhere with $r'=h$. So, maybe I'm missing something, but the claim should be true when we impose the stronger assumption $$g(b)-g(a)=\int_a^bh(t)\:{\rm d}t\;\;\;\text{for all }b\ge a\ge0\tag1$$ for some locally Lebesgue integrable $h:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. Since $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ is generated by $\{(a,b]:a\le b\}$, we should easily see that $$\mu_g=h\lambda$$ from which $(1)$ immediately follows (noting that, necessarily, $h=g'$ Lebesgue almost everywhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g$ is the Cantor function then $g'=0$ almost evrywhere so the right hand side is $0$ for any $f$. Take $f=\chi_{[0,1]}$ to get a contradiction.

Comment: Can we turn the claim to be true?

Comment: If $g$ is absolutely continuous then it is true.  @0xbadf00d

Comment: Okay, I guess in this case $\mu_g$ has a density with respect to $\lambda$ given by $g'$. Is there an easy condition on $g$ ensuring absolute continuity?

Comment: The best known result in that direction is a theorem in Rudin (RCA) which says that if $g$ is differentiable at **every** point and $g'$ is integrable then $g$ is absolutely continuous. @0xbadf00d

Comment: Could you point me to the particular page/theorem in Rudin?

Comment: I don't have an international edition of the book but this result is in the chapter on differentiation. @0xbadf00d

Comment: What goes wrong when $g$ is only differentiable $\lambda$-almost everywhere and $g'\in\mathcal L^1(\lambda)$?

Comment: Are you familiar with singular functions? Cantor function is differentiable almost everywhere and its derivative is $0$ almost everywhere (hence the derivative is intergable). @0xbadf00d

Comment: @0xbadf00d if $g$ is sum of a step function and an absolutely continuous function, then $\int f d\mu_g = \int f g' d\lambda + \sum_{x \in \mathcal{D}} h(x) f(x)$, where $\mathcal{D}$ is a set of all points of discontinuity of $g$, and $h(x) = g(x + 0) - g(x - 0)$. If $g$ contains a singular component, then such reduction is impossible.

Comment: So, the coomment of RRL under [this questino](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4468112/47771) is wrong, right?

Comment: The first comment by RRL there is suerly wrong.

Comment: Please take note of my edit? Do you agree? The imposed stronger assumption should still be weaker than requiring $g$ to be differentiable **everywhere**, right?

Comment: If you have $g(b)-g(a)=\int_a^bh(t)\:{\rm d}t\;\;\;\text{for all }b\ge a\ge0$  then there is no problem.  @0xbadf00d